# Detect when TextBox autocomplete list is showing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have `TextBox` controls and associated Timers that restarts on each `KeyDown` or `MouseClick` event, and performs queries based on typed text after 3 seconds without those events. So far so good.

But some of my TextBoxes also have AutoComplete lists which user can browse in, but even if they do using keyboard arrow keys, timer is not halted and an unexpected query is fired in the middle of user browsing the list.

Question: is there a way of detecting when autocomplete list is showing, so that I can suspend timer or ignoring its tick?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use [`EnumThreadWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633495(v=vs.85).aspx) to find all auto complete dropdown windows and check if any of them is visible. The Auto-complete dropdown window class name is `Auto-Suggest Dropdown`. You can use [`GetClassName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx) method to get class name of enumerated windows and then using [`IsWindowVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530(v=vs.85).aspx) method check if the window is visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`EnumThreadWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633495(v=vs.85).aspx) to find all auto complete dropdown windows and check if any of them is visible. The Auto-complete dropdown window class name is `Auto-Suggest Dropdown`. You can use [`GetClassName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx) method to get class name of enumerated windows and then using [`IsWindowVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530(v=vs.85).aspx) method check if the window is visible.

**Example**

In below example, I used a timer like you have in your code in the question, and in tick event of the timer, I've checked if there is an auto-complete window open I showed "Open" in title of form, otherwise showed "close":

```
Delegate Function EnumThreadDelegate(hWnd As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Shared Function EnumThreadWindows(dwThreadId As Integer, _
    lpfn As EnumThreadDelegate, lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Shared Function GetClassName(ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr,
    lpClassName As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
    nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Shared Function GetCurrentThreadId() As Integer
End Function

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Shared Function IsWindowVisible(hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```

```
Const AutoCompleteClassName As String = "Auto-Suggest Dropdown"
Function EnumThreadCallback(hWnd As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    Dim className As New System.Text.StringBuilder("", 256)
    GetClassName(hWnd, className, 256)
    If className.ToString() = AutoCompleteClassName AndAlso IsWindowVisible(hWnd) Then
        AnAutoCOmpleteIsOpen = True
    End If
    Return True
End Function
Dim AnAutoCOmpleteIsOpen As Boolean = False
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    AnAutoCOmpleteIsOpen = False
    EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), _
        New EnumThreadDelegate(AddressOf Me.EnumThreadCallback), IntPtr.Zero)
    If (AnAutoCOmpleteIsOpen) Then
        Me.Text = "Open"
    Else
        Me.Text = "Close"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @RezaAghaei idol + 1 for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Reza Aghaei's approach translated into C#:

```
public delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(uint dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);
```

```
bool isAutoCompleteListOpen = false;
EnumThreadDelegate callback = (IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam) =>
{
    var cn = new StringBuilder("", 256);
    GetClassName(hwnd, cn, 256);
    if (cn.ToString() == "Auto-Suggest Dropdown" && IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) {
        isAutoCompleteListOpen = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero);
return isAutoCompleteListOpen;
```

For better performance, here we're returning `false` in the callback upon finding an open list, which stops the enumeration.