# How to know if the AutoComplete listbox on an TextBox is open?

Tags: winforms, autocomplete

I have a form with 2 textboxes. The first one has a customsource for its autocompletion set like this :

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = GetUserNames();
```

The GetUserNames() method retuns an AutoCompleteCustomSource and all this works very well.

When this form opens the focus in on the first textbox, the user can type in or choose from the autocomplete and that works well.

Both textboxes have an onKeyDown event and in that event they should do some validations using the values of both textboxes.

I want to keydown to only do its validations when ENTER is pressed when the autocomplete listbox is closed.

Look at it this way:
the user starts typing, a list appears, the user chooses an item from the list and presses enter to confirm his choice, and then he wants to press TAB to go to the next textbox.
But when he presses ENTER after choosing an item in the autocomplete list the keyDown event already fires. At this stage the keydown event should not fire, the ENTER should only confirm the choice from the autocomplete list.

Is there a way to detect in the keydown that ENTER was pressed while the autocomplete list was still open ?
Or is there a way to disable the keydown event while the autocomplete list is open ?

**EDIT:**
from the comments I tried the answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40915048/3110834
Unfortunate it does not works in this case but it has teached me that pressing enter on the autocomplete suggestion does 2 things:

> 1. close the autocomplete window
> 2. fire the keydown event of the textbox

So I need to find a way to stop the keydown event for the textbox to fire when pressing enter on the autocomplete window.

**Edit:**
Things are far worse than I thought.
When you open the autosuggest box and then click on a suggested item to select it, the keydown event also fires and it has Keys.Enter in its KeyCode ! Since when is a click equal to a keystroke ?
How do I stop this ? Is this a bug ?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40915048/3110834) is the solution, implemented using VB.NET: [Detect when TextBox autocomplete list is showing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40915048/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I am trying to convert the answer to C# but I am stuck on New EnumThreadDelegate(AddressOf Me.EnumThreadCallback), IntPtr.Zero). What is the c# method for the AddresOf ? I find many articles about it here but they dont work or i dont understand how to use them in this case

Comment: I finally got it converted to c# but the IsWindowVisible() always returns false. Any idea what could cause this ? When debugging the EnumThreadCallBack the correct classname is there

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for your answer but it does not helps me, it seems that when pressing enter on the auto-suggest dropdown the dropdown first closes, and then the keydown of the textbox fires. And then the IsWindowVisisble will offcourse return false.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem, I followed the approach in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40915048/3110834

if you try to evaluate if there is a list open during the Keydown event, it will always return a false, since the event already closed the list.

instead I observe the PreviewKeyDown event to evaluate if the AutoComplete list is open or not, if it is Open, i unsubscribe from the KeyDown event (which only uses the Enter key on my case) and if the list is close, i re-subscribe to it back again

```
private void tbxAND_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (IsAutoCompleteOpen())
            {
                tbxAND.KeyDown -= tbxAND_KeyDown;
            }
            else
            {
                tbxAND.KeyDown += tbxAND_KeyDown;
            }
        }
    }
```

notice that IsAutoCompleteOpen() starts the code to enumerate the openlist.

this may not be the full solution for this particular case if you still need to catch other keys, but i wanted to leave the hint in case someone else run into this problem.

Comment: Seems like an idea I want to try out, thanks